# File versioning and updating their names in dist files

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, requirejs

I'm struggling in making a dist version of my application. I've packaged my application with r.js (app is using requirejs). So I have

```
dir-
    -index.html
    -css
        -style.css
    -js
        main.js
    assets
        -img1.jpg
        -img2.png
```

Now I'd like to version the dist files and update appropriate dependencies in js, css and html. **What is the suitable tool for versioning and autowiring versioned files with requirejs?**

I've tried using bunch of different versioning plugins from npm such as

```
grunt-version-assets
grunt-assets-versioning
grunt-version
usemin
etc.
```

Have not had much luck with them, some seem to do close to something I need, but not fully.

I've also tried revving the files with `grunt-filerev` and replacing strings in js, css and html. In that I also failed, could not figure out how to properly replace

```
<script data-main="js/main" src="./lib/require.js"></script>
```

And the best result of all would be to lose require.js from dist build all together as it is not needed anymore. Any pointers, tutorials are welcomed.

Comment: Just in case: don't version your filenames, hash! `index-1.0.0.js` is good, but `index-afb56344c.js` is more specific and more easily cached (and you can tie it back to a single revision in source control).

Answer (score -1):

Try any of these two link, it might be helpful and easy to implement also.
1.

```
cacheBust: {
    options: {
        assets: ['assets/**/*'],
        baseDir: './public/'
    },
    taskName: {
        files: [{   
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'public/',
            src: ['templates/**/*.html', 'assets/**/*']
        }]
    }
}
```

for more details go to https://github.com/hollandben/grunt-cache-bust

2.

```
'cache-busting': {
    requirejs: {
        replace: ['tmp/**/*.html'],
        replacement: 'MainApp',
        file: 'tmp/deploy/js/app/MainApp.min.js'
    },
    css: {
        replace: ['tmp/**/*.html'],
        replacement: 'style.css',
        file: 'tmp/deploy/css/style.css',
        cleanup: true //Remove previously generated hashed files.
    }
},
```

for more details go to https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-cache-busting

Comment: I could'nt get cachebuster to work well with require, ended up using grunt-version-assets with slight modifications.